# What DLLs and registry entries are modified by installer?

Tags: c++, dll, windows-xp, registry, windows-installer

I'm trying to debug a C++ app on Windows XP and when I start debug mode, after all the initialization is done, the main window won't show. It works, however, on W7.

So I checked the msi installer I have available for the app and after installing the app, the problem seemed to disappear. I uninstalled the app and it still worked.

I need to know which registry entries and DLLs the installer modified so I can identify the problem. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Not trivially. You can of course take a snapshot of the windows/system32 directory (and hope that this is where the files are installed - it likely is, but you can't be certain), and a snapshot of the registry - and then compare the two.

Comment: You can also turn on diagnostic logging of the msi and review the logs. To enable msi logging - install from the command line using: `msiexec /i WhatYouAreInstalling.msi /l*v c:\WhereYouWantToLog.log`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. The issue was that the app would try to acquire a lock on null objects, fail at it, and then release the lock. So when a next acquire would be made, the app would crash. It's strange that the same code works just fine on Windows 7, but my guess is that there some improvements in the Win API, in the lock sections.

*Process Monitor* would've been useful, but the installer had waaay too many threads and registry changes to be able to follow. The *snapshot* would've been as complicated as *Process Monitor* and *diagnostic logging*.

Thank you for your help, guys :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Microsoft's [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) is free and tracks every file I/O and registry read/write a program makes, including an installer. However, there will likely be *many* such changes.

Because `procmon` works by monitoring processes as they run, you'll have to run the installer again.